# Finding Sub Graph from Graph in Neo4J 2.20

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

There are five nodes with their IDs

> A(13), B(14), C(15), D(16), E(17)

I want to find sub graph for Node A

For that i used

```
START user=node (13), follower=node (14, 15, 16, 17) 
MATCH user-[:t1_orange|t2_violet|t3_green|t4_blue*1] ->follower
RETURN user, follower
```

But, I got all nodes with all relationship between the items.

Can anyone tell me and modify my query to get sub graph for Node A in outgoing direction.

Comment: Do you mean the visualisation of Neo4j browser?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you're looking for all nodes who have some relationship to node A?

You could:

```
MATCH (a)-->(b)
WHERE a.id = 13
RETURN a, b
```

or if you're looking for more path oriented query:

```
MATCH path = (a)-[:t1_orange|t2_violet|t3_green|t4_blue*1]->(b)
WHERE a.id = 13
RETURN DISTINCT(path)
```

or if you'd like a list of id within that subgraph:

```
MATCH (a)-->(b)
WHERE a.id = 13
RETURN b.id
```